# Running an error after the project is packaged

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

The project runs normally in eclipse, but there is a problem when the project is packaged and runs in the terminal. How should this problem be solved?

> D:>java -jar
>   optaplanner-examples-7.4.1.Final-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   D:\roster_450.xml 100 Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getInstance(ServiceRegistry.java:27)
>           at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory$LazyHolder.(KieServices.java:332)
>           at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory.get(KieServices.java:339)
>           at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:460)
>           at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:331)
>           at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:220)
>           at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
>           at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolver(CommonApp.java:105)
>           at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.createSolutionBusiness(NurseRosteringApp.java:94)
>           at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.init(NurseRosteringApp.java:85)
>           at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.main(NurseRosteringApp.java:77)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Child services
>   [org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers] have no parent
>           at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.buildMap(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:186)
>           at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.getServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:97)
>           at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistryImpl.(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:36)
>           at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistryImpl$LazyHolder.(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:32)
>           ... 11 more

Comment: Version `7.4.1`? jar-with-dependencies? Where did you get that file?

Comment: Hello, packing 7.7.0 version is also the same mistake, packaged successfully, but the same error occurred at runtime.

Comment: The JAR file I got was just the JAR generated after my package was successful.

Comment: Looks like a classloading problem because you're uber-jarring.

Comment: Please tell me how to solve this problem, thank you. I just didn't know what I just used to do with optaplanner. Thanks again

Comment: Hello Geoffrey De Smet，I want to know the solution to this problem. Please let me know. Thank you！If there is no solution, my task will not be completed.Thank you Geoffrey De Smet

Comment: I observed that the contents of 7.0.0,7.1.0's optaplanner-core-7.x.0.Final.jar kie.conf file are

[

'assemblers': [new org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.kie.KieSolverAssemblerService ()],

'weavers': [],

'runtimes': [],

'beliefs': []

]



After 7.2.0, the kie.conf in optaplanner-core-7.x.0.Final.jar is org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers = +org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.kie.KieSolverAssemblerService



 I don't know if this will be the reason.

Comment: Both 7.0.0 and 7.1.0 can normally be packaged and run, but the jar after packaging after 7.2.0 appears the above error.

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet 7.0.0 and 7.1.0 seem to have kie.conf only in optaplanner-core-7.1.0.Final.jar. However, kie.conf files appear in at least four jar after 7.2.0.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, is it still a problem with uber-jarring with 7.40.0?

Answer (score 1):

Drools doesn't like uber-jarring because several jars have a META-INF directory with files with the same name. So last-one-wins.

Either don't use uber-jarring or doing use Drools score calculation.

Comment: How do I operate if I modify the contents of the project and want to pack and use jar normally?

Comment: It's like the 7.0.0 and 7.1.0 versions